# "It was a litany of gratitude to put an Oscar-winner to shame."

Tags: meaning, idioms

What is the meaning of the above sentence?

It was used in "[Life after Noynoy](http://www.economist.com/news/asia/21660179-president-looks-back-rest-country-thinks-about-his-successor-life-after-noynoy)," an article appearing in the August 1, 2015, issue of *The Economist.*

Extract:

> IT WAS a litany of gratitude to put an Oscar-winner to shame. In his
>   last state-of-the-nation address to the Philippine Congress on July
>   27th, President Benigno “Noynoy” Aquino thanked God, his late parents
>   and political allies, along with his social secretary, hairdresser and
>   clothes stylist. “We are”, he added, “only in the first chapter of the
>   great story of the Filipino people.”

Comment: "Litany of gratitude to put an Oscar-winner to shame" is referring to an extremely long and effusive giving of thanks, ad nauseum.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, the definitions

***[litany](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/litany)***

> (noun) a prolonged or tedious account

[Dictionary.com]

***[put to shame](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/put--to--shame)***

> (idiom),
>
> a. to cause to suffer shame or disgrace.
>
> **b. to outdo; surpass**

[Dictionary.com]

Coming to your sentence:

> It was a litany of gratitude that put an Oscar-winner to shame

---

This implies that the "litany of gratitude", which I presume means some sort of vote of thanks by the speaker, was so good or impressive that it surpassed the levels of acceptance speech by Academy Award winners. Usually, Oscar winning actors are known for their acceptance speech thanking their family, friends, fans, the entire film fraternity, their fish and the rest of the whole wide world for the Award and it tends to be quite gripping. In your case, "the litany of gratitude" outdid the Oscar Winners!

Comment: @user155009 - You're welcome! Please consider accepting this answer if you feel it solved your problem.